# PHP + mysql poll

Tags: php, mysql, performance, voting-system

I am working on a voting system.

The uniqueness of the votes is assured because the user needs to be logged to vote and I keep a record for each vote as a (user, option) pair.

A user can upvote, downvote, or unvote an option, similar to how reddit, or stackoverflow voting system works.

My question is related to how I can return the results. Is it ok to use the mysql COUNT() function every time (to count all votes with a given option_id), or is it better to have a count field for the option itself? The problem with the count field is that I have to somehow keep it synchronized with the vote records. On the other hand, for many options and votes, isn't the mysql COUNT() approach an overkill?

I am looking for an efficient architectural pattern for this kind of voting systems.

**Edit for table structure description**

Unfortunately, I don't have a design tool so I can't draw the table structure. The structure is not that complex, so I can explain it in words.

I have tables for polls, options and votes. One poll can have many options, and one option can have many votes, each vote can be an up_vote or a down_vote. Each vote has a foreign key pointing to one option, for which the vote was made and one foreign key pointing to one user, so I can uniquely identify a vote by a (user, option) pair.

Comment: Does the site have significant enough volume that it would make a difference?  I'd start with the clearest expression of logic you can make in the code and optimize only when a bottleneck has been identified.

Comment: I haven't published the site yet, but it just bothers me, because COUNT()-ing each time looks like a lot of overhead. If I have a page with 100 options, I would need to make 200 COUNT() calls (2 for each option, for the up and down votes). It just looks inefficient .

Comment: If you need to make 200 COUNTs for 100 options, then you database design is clearly wrong. Can you post your related table structure?

Comment: I have edited the post, explaining in words how the table is structured. I suspect my design is wrong, that's why I'm asking the question in the first place. But how else can I count the number of up_votes and down_votes for each option? Or how else to save them to begin with?